# Printing location in memory when printing in the main method objects java

Tags: java, object, methods, printing, program-entry-point

This is printing me the location in memory, why is this happening and how can i fix it.

This is the question of the homework, or exam:

3. The method multiply multiplies the numerator of this RationalNumber by the numerator of r, and the denominator of this RationalNumber by the denominator of r. Which of the following can be used to replace /* missing code */ so that the multiply() method will work as intended?

These are the solutions and i need to choose:

```
num = num * r.num;
den = den * r.den;





this.num = this.num * r.num;
this.den = this.den * r.den;







num = num * r.getNum();
den = den * r.getDen();
```

I tried everything but nothing works.

Here is my code:

```
public class RationalNumber {
    private int num;
    private int den; // den != 0

    /** Constructs a RationalNumber object.
     *  @param n the numerator
     *  @param d the denominator
     *  Precondition: d != 0
     */
    public RationalNumber(int n, int d) {
        num = n;
        den = d;
    }

    /** Multiplies this RationalNumber by r.
     *  @param r a RationalNumber object
     *  Precondition: this.den() != 0
     */
    public void multiply(RationalNumber r) {
        /* missing code */
        num = num * r.num;
        den = den * r.den;

         //this.num = this.num * r.num;
        //this.den = this.den * r.den;

        //num = num * r.getNum();
       //den = den * r.getDen();
    }

    /** @return the numerator
     */
    public int getNum() {
        /* implementation not shown */
        return num;
    }

    /** @return the denominator
     */
    public int getDen() {
        /* implementation not shown */
        return den;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        RationalNumber num = new RationalNumber(10, -1);
        System.out.println(num);


    }

    // Other methods not shown.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override toString() method of the RationalNumber class.

```
System.out.println(num);
```

The code above will print the return value of the toString() method of the provided class if we didn't specify any specific attributes or methods of the class.

Since your RationalNumber class didn't override toString(), it looks for its superclass toString() (The Object class).

You could solve this by adding

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return num + "/" + den;
}
```

After that, you will need to have 2 RationalNumber objects.

For example, in mathematic, <sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>2</sub> * <sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>3</sub> = <sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>6</sub>

In your main method will have something like this

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    RationalNumber rn1 = RationalNumber(1,2); //This represent 1/2
    RationalNUmber rn2 = RationalNumber(1,3); //This represent 1/3
    rn1.multiply(rn2); //This equals to 1/2 * 1/3, it multiply the num and den variable of rn1 object with rn2
    System.out.println(rn1); //This will invoke the toString() of rn1
}
```

Comment: Thanks but still now it just prints the numerator and denominator and still not the result of the operation given above

Comment: This is because you haven't invoke the multiply(RationalNumber r) method.

Comment: I have edited the answer which will invoke the multiply operation.